# Algorithm to round about n * 10

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying to find an algorithm to result:

```
45 => 100
458 => 1000
8456 => 10000
```

I would like to "round" this way, i looked into `Math.round()` but it doesn't think to be enough.

Comment: Take log to the base 10 and round up?

Comment: are you always going to be rounding up? (hence the 45 -> 100) would 1001 round to 10000 then?

Comment: Are you trying to round `45 => 50 => 100`?

Comment: Replace each digit with a 0 and prepend a number 1.
Something like `Integer.parseInt("1" + String.valueOf(45).replaceAll("[0-9]", "0"));`

Comment: `n * 10`? Don't you mean `n^10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest thing to come up with without thinking:

```
var n = 455;
var rounded;

for(var i = 1000000000 i>= 1; i/=10)
{
    if(i < n)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        rounded = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, inspired by your idea:

`var n = 455;
var rounded;
for(var i = 1; i<= n; i*=10)
{
    if(i > n)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        rounded = i*10;
    }
}`

Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

For a single line of code you can do what Rup said. A base 10 log will give you the closest power of 10, then do ten to the power of the ceiling of the result of the log

```
var x = 45;

Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log(x) / Math.LN10));
```